# location path comes as undefined in react application

Tags: reactjs

I am having below `js` file in react application

```
      const Header = (props) => {
         const pathName = props?.location?.pathName;

         return (
              //html
          );
      };

      export default withRouter(Header);
```

Here `pathName` always comes as undefined, and because of which page redirection is not happening.

Console has below errors

[image]

Here is my package versions

```
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-bootstrap": "^2.7.2",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-router": "^6.8.1",
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
"react-scripts": "5.0.1",
"web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `location.pathname` not `location.pathName`.